# How I can select dynamic generated Id by jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, select, dynamic

I have dynamic generated Id by PHP:

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary register" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="Register" />
```

How I can select this input by jquery?

```
$('#wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>').val();
```

Does not work

Thanks!

Comment: You should set a class to select, like `$('.wp-submit-register').val()`.

Comment: If the ID is dynamic then I don't understand why you would want to bind an event to that specific element with that specific ID. As above, you should use a class instead.

Comment: And is that Wordpress, if so, there's a special way to pass values to your scripts.

Comment: if thats the only button that with dynamic id? you can use `$('input[id^="wp-submit"]').val();`, this will select whatever id that start with keyword "wp-submit"

Comment: Do you have multiple submit buttons on this page?

Answer (score 2):

Given the name `wp-submit` and the variable `$template->the_instance()`, I'm guessing Wordpress

The right way to do that in Wordpress, is to localize the script when you include it, and pass values to the script that way

```
<?php

    wp_register_script( 'my_script', 'path/to/myscript.js', array( 'jquery' ));

    $values_to_pass = array( 'instance' => $template->the_instance() );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'object_name', $values_to_pass );

    // The script can be enqueued now or later.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );

?>
```

now inside your javascript file you can do

```
$('#wp-submit' + object_name.instance ).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're outputting that js code in an inline `<script>` tag as part of the page you're generating, then all you need to do is add an `echo` in the PHP in there. (This wouldn't work as part of an external JS file)

```
... page content
<script>
   $('#wp-submit<?php echo $template->the_instance(); ?>').val();
</script>
```

Note - you'll also want to do the same to your ID attribute to get the value to show up.

```
id="wp-submit<?php echo $template->the_instance(); ?>"
```

Comment: How do you know that `$template->the_instance()` doesn't already echo a value?

Comment: @ChristianVarga Good point. I made an assumption about that without even realising it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need id. Use `$('.register')`

**EDIT** ok, you can get it by `$('input[type=submit].register')`

cause it's never a good idea to mix server- and client-side languages

Comment: A class is designed to be used on several different elements. Suppose he uses `.register` in multiple fields. Is your solution still applicable?

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell, yes it WILL select this input as OP asked, `on submit` you can perform any verification: id, type, etc.

Comment: But if you have ten elements with the same class, it WILL select all ten elements

Comment: @adeneo of course, it's obvious to bind submit event to all "Register" buttons on page (even if they are multiple, though I think it's alone there) and then check